# Creating a Boolean Binary Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need to initialize a binary search tree to have all false values.  I am given the height.  First time trying to create a tree.  All the examples I can find typically don't have boolean values.  I am not getting errors but I am in an infinite loop right now.  I'm going to guess that the error is most likely creating the new nodes :/

```cpp
template<class type>
struct binTreeNode {
    bool value;
    binTreeNode <bool> *left,*right;
};

void createTree(int height){
    binTreeNode <bool> *root;
    root = new binTreeNode <bool>;
    root -> value = false;

    int copyHeight = height;
    copyHeight=copyHeight-1; //Because
    //Created Root already?

    while(copyHeight>0){
        root->left = new binTreeNode <bool>;
        root->right = new binTreeNode <bool>;
        binTreeNode <bool> *it;

        it = root->left;
        it -> value= false;

        it = root->right;
        it -> value= false;
        copyHeight--;
    }
};
```

Comment: the code is weird. you don't use type parameter at all, the loop only fills two nodes below root and there is no infinite loop.

Comment: What's your full program? What value are you calling `createTree` with?

Comment: A binary search tree of booleans will never have more than two nodes, and a binary search tree of all false values is nonsensical. You must have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the template argument is not even used, as you have already indicated in your `value` type that the binary tree holds only a `bool` type. So not sure why you have that there.

I would say a more concise approach for this problem would be to use an initializer list and a recursive function, as so

```
struct binTreeNode {
   bool value;
   struct binTreeNode* lfs;
   struct binTreeNode* rfs;

   binTreeNode(bool value, binTreeNode* lfs = nullptr, binTreeNode* rfs = nullptr): value(value), lfs(lfs), rfs(rfs) {}
};

binTreeNode* createTree(unsigned height) {
    if (height == 1) {
      return new binTreeNode(false);
    } else {
      return new binTreeNode(false, createTree(height-1), createTree(height-1));
    }
}
```

Using recursion emphasizes that the tree keeps growing until the height becomes 1, in which the last, leaf node is constructed.

As a side note, if you wanted to replicate this idea of initializing any typed binary tree, you could then use a template parameter in the node type, like so

```
template<class T>
struct binTreeNode {
   T value;
   struct binTreeNode* lfs;
   struct binTreeNode* rfs;

   binTreeNode(const T& value, binTreeNode* lfs = nullptr, binTreeNode* rfs = nullptr): value(value), lfs(lfs), rfs(rfs) {}
};

template<class T>
binTreeNode<T>* createTree(unsigned height, const T& value) {
    if (height == 1) {
      return new binTreeNode(value);
    } else {
      return new binTreeNode(value, createTree<T>(height-1), createTree<T>(height-1));
    }
}
```